# v-dialog don't open when in v-data-table

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js

i am trying to do something quite similar to CRUD action with a v-dialog.

Here is the example:
https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/#crud-actions

And here was my code:

```
<template>
    <v-container>
        <h1>Admin BDE</h1>
        <v-card>
            <v-card-title>
                Etudiants
                <v-spacer></v-spacer>
                <v-text-field
                    v-model="rechercheUtilisateur"
                    label="Recherche"
                    class="mx-4"
                    clearable
                ></v-text-field>
            </v-card-title>
            <v-data-table
                :headers="headersUtilisateur"
                :items="utilisateurs"
                :items-per-page="10"
                :search="rechercheUtilisateur"
                :custom-filter="filtrerUtilisateur"
                class="elevation-1"
            >
            <v-dialog
                v-model="dialogUtilisateur"
                max-width="500px"
            >
                <v-card>
                    <v-card-text>
                        <v-container>
                            <v-row>
                                <v-col
                                    cols="12"
                                    sm="6"
                                    md="4"
                                >
                                    <v-text-field
                                        v-model="editedItem.points"
                                        label="Points"
                                    ></v-text-field>
                                </v-col>
                                <v-col
                                    cols="12"
                                    sm="6"
                                    md="4"
                                >
                                    <v-btn
                                        color="blue darken-1"
                                        text
                                        @click="sauvegarderModificationUtilisateur"
                                    >
                                    Enregistrer
                                    </v-btn>
                                </v-col>
                            </v-row>
                        </v-container>
                    </v-card-text>
                </v-card>
            </v-dialog>
            <template v-slot:[`item.actions`]="{ item }">
      <v-icon
        small
        class="mr-2"
        @click="editItem(item)"
      >
        mdi-pencil
      </v-icon>
    </template>
            </v-data-table>
        </v-card>
        <div style="margin-top: 40px;"></div>
        <v-card>
            <v-card-title>
                Poster nouveau message
            </v-card-title>
            <v-card-text>
                <v-text-field
                    label="Titre du message"
                    v-model="titreMessage"
                    clearable
                ></v-text-field>
                <v-textarea
                    label="Corps du message"
                    v-model="corpsMessage"
                ></v-textarea>
            </v-card-text>
        </v-card>
    </v-container>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'AdminBDE',
  data: () => ({
        utilisateurs: [
            {
                prenom: "Jean",
                nom: "Roger",
                mail: "jean@test.com",
                numeroEtudiant: 1,
                promo: "jsai ap"
            },
            {
                prenom: "Beau",
                nom: "Gosse",
                mail: "beau@test.com",
                numeroEtudiant: 2,
                promo: "jsai ap"
            },
            {
                prenom: "Belle",
                nom: "Gueule",
                mail: "belle@test.com",
                numeroEtudiant: 3,
                promo: "jsai ap"
            },
            {
                prenom: "Zebi",
                nom: "LaMouche",
                mail: "zebi@test.com",
                numeroEtudiant: 4,
                promo: "danse"
            },
            {
                prenom: "Cassius",
                nom: "Clay",
                mail: "cassius@test.com",
                numeroEtudiant: 5,
                promo: "box"
            }
        ],
        rechercheUtilisateur: "",
        titreMessage: "",
        corpsMessage: "",
        dialogUtilisateur: false,
        editedItem: {
            points: 0
        },
        defaultItem: {
            points: 0
        }
    }),
    computed: {
        headersUtilisateur() {
            return [
                {
                    text: "Nom",
                    value: "nom"
                },
                {
                    text: "Prenom",
                    value: "prenom"
                },
                {
                    text: "Mail",
                    value: "mail"
                },
                {
                    text: "Classe",
                    value: "promo"
                },
                {
                    text: "Actions",
                    value: "actions",
                    sortable: false
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    watch: {
        dialogUtilisateur(val) {
            console.log("test val", val)
            val || this.fermer()
        }
    },
    methods: {
        filtrerUtilisateur(value, search) {
            return value != null &&
            search != null &&
            typeof value === 'string' &&
            value.toString().toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(search) !== -1
        },
        editItem (item) {
            console.log("test item", item)
            this.editedIndex = this.utilisateurs.indexOf(item)
            this.editedItem = Object.assign({}, item)
            this.dialogUtilisateur = true
        },
        fermer () {
            this.dialogUtilisateur = false
            this.$nextTick(() => {
                this.editedItem = Object.assign({}, this.defaultItem)
                this.editedIndex = -1
            })
        },
        sauvegarderModificationUtilisateur() {
            if (this.editedIndex > -1) {
                Object.assign(this.utilisateurs[this.editedIndex], this.editedItem)
            }
            this.fermer()
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

It didn't work, so i tried this:

```
<template>
    <v-container>
        <h1>Admin BDE</h1>
        <v-card>
            <v-card-title>
                Etudiants
                <v-spacer></v-spacer>
                <v-text-field
                    v-model="rechercheUtilisateur"
                    label="Recherche"
                    class="mx-4"
                    clearable
                ></v-text-field>
            </v-card-title>
            <v-dialog
                v-model="dialogUtilisateur"
                max-width="500px"
            >
                <v-card>
                    <v-card-text>
                        <v-container>
                            <v-row>
                                <v-col
                                    cols="12"
                                    sm="6"
                                    md="4"
                                >
                                    <v-text-field
                                        v-model="editedItem.points"
                                        label="Points"
                                    ></v-text-field>
                                </v-col>
                                <v-col
                                    cols="12"
                                    sm="6"
                                    md="4"
                                >
                                    <v-btn
                                        color="blue darken-1"
                                        @click="sauvegarderModificationUtilisateur"
                                    >
                                    Enregistrer
                                    </v-btn>
                                </v-col>
                            </v-row>
                        </v-container>
                    </v-card-text>
                </v-card>
            </v-dialog>
            <v-data-table
                :headers="headersUtilisateur"
                :items="utilisateurs"
                :items-per-page="10"
                :search="rechercheUtilisateur"
                :custom-filter="filtrerUtilisateur"
                class="elevation-1"
            >
            <template v-slot:[`item.actions`]="{ item }">
      <v-icon
        small
        class="mr-2"
        @click="editItem(item)"
      >
        mdi-pencil
      </v-icon>
    </template>
            </v-data-table>
        </v-card>
        <div style="margin-top: 40px;"></div>
        <v-card>
            <v-card-title>
                Poster nouveau message
            </v-card-title>
            <v-card-text>
                <v-text-field
                    label="Titre du message"
                    v-model="titreMessage"
                    clearable
                ></v-text-field>
                <v-textarea
                    label="Corps du message"
                    v-model="corpsMessage"
                ></v-textarea>
            </v-card-text>
            <v-card-actions>
                <v-btn
                    color="primary"
                    @click="ajoutMessage"
                > Ajouter
                </v-btn>
            </v-card-actions>
        </v-card>
    </v-container>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'AdminBDE',
  data: () => ({
        utilisateurs: [
            {
                prenom: "Jean",
                nom: "Roger",
                mail: "jean@test.com",
                numeroEtudiant: 1,
                promo: "jsai ap",
                points: 0
            },
            {
                prenom: "Beau",
                nom: "Gosse",
                mail: "beau@test.com",
                numeroEtudiant: 2,
                promo: "jsai ap",
                points: 0
            },
            {
                prenom: "Belle",
                nom: "Gueule",
                mail: "belle@test.com",
                numeroEtudiant: 3,
                promo: "jsai ap",
                points: 0
            },
            {
                prenom: "Zebi",
                nom: "LaMouche",
                mail: "zebi@test.com",
                numeroEtudiant: 4,
                promo: "danse",
                points: 0
            },
            {
                prenom: "Cassius",
                nom: "Clay",
                mail: "cassius@test.com",
                numeroEtudiant: 5,
                promo: "box",
                points: 0
            }
        ],
        rechercheUtilisateur: "",
        titreMessage: "",
        corpsMessage: "",
        dialogUtilisateur: false,
        editedItem: {
            points: 0
        },
        defaultItem: {
            points: 0
        }
    }),
    computed: {
        headersUtilisateur() {
            return [
                {
                    text: "Nom",
                    value: "nom"
                },
                {
                    text: "Prenom",
                    value: "prenom"
                },
                {
                    text: "Nombre de points",
                    value: "points"
                },
                {
                    text: "Mail",
                    value: "mail"
                },
                {
                    text: "Classe",
                    value: "promo"
                },
                {
                    text: "Actions",
                    value: "actions",
                    sortable: false
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    watch: {
        dialogUtilisateur(val) {
            console.log("test val", val)
            val || this.fermer()
        }
    },
    methods: {
        filtrerUtilisateur(value, search) {
            return value != null &&
            search != null &&
            typeof value === 'string' &&
            value.toString().toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(search) !== -1
        },
        editItem (item) {
            console.log("test item", item)
            this.editedIndex = this.utilisateurs.indexOf(item)
            this.editedItem = Object.assign({}, item)
            this.dialogUtilisateur = true
        },
        fermer () {
            this.dialogUtilisateur = false
            this.$nextTick(() => {
                this.editedItem = Object.assign({}, this.defaultItem)
                this.editedIndex = -1
            })
        },
        sauvegarderModificationUtilisateur() {
            if (this.editedIndex > -1) {
                Object.assign(this.utilisateurs[this.editedIndex], this.editedItem)
            }
            this.fermer()
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Basically i put the v-dialog out of the v-data-table and it works.

Now i'm happy my code work, but i don't understand why it didn't work when i did the same than the doc.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i see correctly, in the vuetify example v-dialog component in

```
    <template v-slot:top>
```

But in your example it is on default slot. Probably v-data-table does not render default slot.

```
 <v-data-table
  :headers="headersUtilisateur"
  :items="utilisateurs"
  :items-per-page="10"
  :search="rechercheUtilisateur"
  :custom-filter="filtrerUtilisateur"
  class="elevation-1"
>
  <template v-slot:top>
    <v-dialog
      v-model="dialogUtilisateur"
      max-width="500px"
    >
      <v-card>
        <v-card-text>
          <v-container>
            <v-row>
              <v-col
                cols="12"
                sm="6"
                md="4"
              >
                <v-text-field
                  v-model="editedItem.points"
                  label="Points"
                ></v-text-field>
              </v-col>
              <v-col
                cols="12"
                sm="6"
                md="4"
              >
                <v-btn
                  color="blue darken-1"
                  text
                  @click="sauvegarderModificationUtilisateur"
                >
                  Enregistrer
                </v-btn>
              </v-col>
            </v-row>
          </v-container>
        </v-card-text>
      </v-card>
    </v-dialog>
  </template>
    <template v-slot:[`item.actions`]="{ item }">
      <v-icon
        small
        class="mr-2"
        @click="editItem(item)"
      >
        mdi-pencil
      </v-icon>
    </template>
</v-data-table>
```

I think this works.

Comment: Indeed it works.
What do you mean by do not render default slot exactly ?
sorry i'm noob =/

Comment: When you write component you make slots to render html template from outside. You need to manage slots from inside of the component.
`<my-default-component> I am default slot </my-default-component>`
it is equal to this in MyDefaultComponent.vue
`<template>
<slot> </slot>
</template>`
 I think v-data-table does not manage default slot. Because of the that your html code does not apply to the v-datatable.
My English is not so good i hope i helped :)